# Python: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in netCDF data

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a parameter called air(time, level, lat, lon) from netCDF data on basemap but I keep on getting an error of "too many values to unpack(expected 2)" despite calling all the variables in it. Below is my code

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

nc = NetCDFFile('/home/bernard/Desktop/air.2018.nc')

mp = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-60,urcrnrlat=80,llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180, resolution = 'i')

longitude, latitude = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y, = mp(longitude, latitude)
c_scheme = mp.pcolor(x,y, np.squeeze(air[0,:,:,:]), cmap = 'jet')
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-a761af05237e> in <module>
----> 1 c_scheme = mp.pcolor(x,y, np.squeeze(air[0,:,:,:]), cmap = 'jet')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in with_transform(self, x, y, data, *args, **kwargs)
    544             # convert lat/lon coords to map projection coords.
    545             x, y = self(x,y)
--> 546         return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
    547     return with_transform
    548 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in pcolor(self, x, y, data, **kwargs)
   3394                 x = ma.masked_values(np.where(x > 1.e20,1.e20,x), 1.e20)
   3395                 y = ma.masked_values(np.where(y > 1.e20,1.e20,y), 1.e20)
-> 3396                 ret = ax.pcolor(x,y,data,**kwargs)
   3397         finally:
   3398             self._restore_hold(ax)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1597     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1598         if data is None:
-> 1599             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1600 
   1601         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in pcolor(self, alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, *args, **kwargs)
   5901         always discards the last row and column of *C*.
   5902         """
-> 5903         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)
   5904         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   5905 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in _pcolorargs(funcname, allmatch, *args)
   5732                 if isinstance(Y, np.ma.core.MaskedArray):
   5733                     Y = Y.data
-> 5734             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   5735         else:
   5736             raise TypeError(

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What lines does throw the error ? If that is `x, y, = mp(longitude, latitude)`, then do `print(mp(longitude, latitude))` and you'll see if it gives out 2 values

Comment: the very last line c_scheme is the one which does give the error

Comment: Can you [edit] and share the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: @azro I have added it

Comment: Looks like there are more than two values returned where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Ben Y that's what I was also thinking, but I was unable to solve it